# Functional Derivative for Functional on a Manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds, calculus-of-variations

I have a question about the definition of the functional derivative from Wikipedia:

> **Functional derivative:**
>   Given a manifold $M$ representing (continuous/smooth) functions $\rho$  (with certain boundary conditions etc.), and a functional $F$ defined as 
>   $$F\colon M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad \mbox{or} \quad F\colon M \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \, ,$$
>   the functional derivative $F[\rho]$, denoted $\frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho}$, is defined by:
>   \begin{align}
>  \int \frac{\delta F}{\delta\rho}(x) \phi(x) \; dx 
> &= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{F[\rho+\varepsilon \phi]-F[\rho]}{\varepsilon} \\
> &= \left [ \frac{d}{d\epsilon}F[\rho+\epsilon \phi]\right ]_{\epsilon=0},
> \end{align}
>   where $\phi$ is an arbitrary function.

Since the functional is defined on a manifold, I am wondering how one can consider the sum $\rho + \epsilon \phi$ and evaluate $F(\rho + \epsilon \phi)$?

Comment: You cannot. The whole article is informal, to say the least. Take a look at the Gateaux derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) for a mathematically rigorous formulation of the functional derivative.

Comment: What about this: If $M$ represents the set of some (real-valued) functions defined on some space $X$, then there is a vector space structure on $M$ coming from $\mathbb R$ (addition of real valued functions, etc.). If $M$ represents functions with some boundary conditions $\rho\rvert_{\partial X} = g$, then $M$ is an affine space modeled on the space of functions $\phi$ with $\phi\rvert_{\partial X} = 0$. Then $\rho + \epsilon \phi$ makes sense, shouldn't it?